# Pixels per inch for iOS icons?

Tags: ios, icons

I've been trying to figure out a workflow so our GA can send us icons that we can then use in both iOS and Android. After many different attempts, I received a 1024x1024 .AI file, and surprise, surprise, Preview can open it.

So now all I have to do is save it out as a PNG... at which point Preview asks me for a Resolution...

a) does this setting do anything in this case?

b) should I just set it to 72?

Answer (score 0):

As a graphical designer, the PPI is pretty much the quality of your photos. The higher the better but 72 is ideal. That is what I always use and I've never had any issues.

Comment: Thanks Ed! I'll save it up now!

Comment: No probs, let me know how you go.